# Eclipse Helios Java EE with Postgres 9.0

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to crack out some simple examples with Eclipse Helios Java EE and Postgres 9.0. When I try to configure JPA data source with Postgres 9.0. The data source is created and the test connection works. But in the data source window , the tables under the 'public' schema never gets listed. I updated the datasource to use the latest Postgres 9.0 Jdbc type 4 drivers. Since the tables dont get listed , under JPA tools , the generate entities from tables wont work. What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

In connection properties set URL to one of this formats:

```
jdbc:postgresql:database
jdbc:postgresql://host/database
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
```